# gnuplot: how to avoid viewing angle dependent semitransparent 3D surfaces?

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, transparency

I stumbled accross the following.
If I plot, e.g. a cube using `pm3d` and define the sides to be semitransparent, I would expect that the cube looks the same if I rotate it by multiple of 90 degrees.
However, apparently depending on the viewing angle a particular surface appears brighter or darker than the others. In the example below the views at 30 and 120 degrees have 3 different shades of red whereas the view at 210 and 300 degrees have only 2 shades of red. There is no `pm3d lighting` involved.

**Questions:**
How can this be explained? How can this be avoided? Is something wrong with my definition of the cube?
Did I miss anything in the documentation under `help pm3d` or `help pm3d algorithm` or `help pm3d color_assignment`? Am I using a too old gnuplot version (5.2.8) or "wrong" terminal (wxt)?

**Code:**

```
### semitransparent 3D surfaces
reset session

$Cube <<EOD
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 1
0 1 0
0 0 0

1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 1
1 1 0
1 0 0

0 0 0
1 0 0
1 1 0
0 1 0
0 0 0

0 0 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
0 1 1
0 0 1
EOD

set view equal xyz
set cbrange [0.9:1]
set palette defined (1 'red')
set pm3d depthorder hidden3d
set pm3d implicit
unset hidden3d
unset label
unset tics
unset border
unset key
unset colorbox

set multiplot layout 2,3
    a=75
    b=30
    r=1.3
    set title sprintf("opaque view: %d, %d",a,b)
    set view a,b,r
    set style fill transparent solid 1
    splot $Cube u 1:2:3:(1) w l lw 0.5 lc "black"
    
    set style fill transparent solid 0.3
    do for [i=30:300:90] {
        set title sprintf("transparent view: %d, %d",a,i)
        set view a,i
        replot
    }
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple things are happening here

1. Initially I thought that part of what you are seeing is evidence that the compositing operation of the graphics rendering in whichever terminal you are using is non-transitive.  However I think that most or all of the effect can be explained without this.

   ```
     (background ∘ 0.3red) ∘ 0.3red  ?=?  background ∘ (0.3red ∘ 0.3red)
   ```
2. One key is that your "cube" is not really a cube; it is missing 2 faces.  Differential effect of the view angle is much more obvious if you draw them as polygons:

   ```
   unset pm3d
   splot $Cube u 1:2:3 w polygons
   ```
3. Because you are using `with pm3d`, the program is trying to interpret the vertices as a set of scan lines defining a surface.  This doesn't really work.  I am not entirely sure what it ends up with but I suspect some of the areas are drawn twice.  You can get a feel for what is going wrong here by drawing it again with

   ```
    set pm3d interpolate 2,2
   ```

[image]

If you add the missing two faces of the cube and draw the faces `with polygons` the effect disappears entirely.

```
set view equal xyz
unset hidden3d
unset tics
unset border
unset key

set multiplot layout 2,3
    a=75
    b=30
    r=1.3
    set title sprintf("opaque view: %d, %d",a,b)
    set view a,b,r
    set style fill transparent solid 1
    set pm3d border lw 0.5 lc "black"
    splot $Cube u 1:2:3 w polygons fc "red"
    
    set style fill transparent solid 0.3
    do for [i=30:300:90] {
        set title sprintf("transparent view: %d, %d",a,i)
        set view a,i
        replot
    }
unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your explanations. It should be mentioned that `with polygons` requires gnuplot 5.4. I guess I still don't fully understand `pm3d`. When plotting the opaque cube (as you said with the missing two sides) and rotate it manually I can not "look inside" because the "inside" lines are hidden, so I assumed the cube is closed with 6 surfaces. But apparently somehow it is not. Well, that's another issue. The original question is answered, thanks again.